# Python Youtube Api Developer Key

Tags: python, google-api, youtube-api, google-api-python-client

I'm running the code is coming blank ?

which one is right ?

1 - DEVELOPER_KEY = "AIzaSyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

2 - DEVELOPER_KEY = "779749880288-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"

"""

```
import os

import googleapiclient.discovery

from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload


def main():

    os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

    api_service_name = "youtube"
    api_version = "v3"
    DEVELOPER_KEY = "AIzaSyCtHy6xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)

    request = youtube.videos().insert(
        part="snippet,status",
        body={
            "snippet": {
                "categoryId": "22",
                "description": "Description of uploaded video.",
                "title": "Test video upload."
            },
            "status": {
                "privacyStatus": "private"
            }
        },

        media_body=MediaFileUpload("/Users/mac/Desktop/Projelerim/dos/video.avi")
    )
    response = request.execute()

    print(response) """
```

Comment: I forgot to add him to the end                                                                               if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Comment: line 54, in <module>
    main() .  I get this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither.

> [videos.insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) Uploads a video to YouTube and optionally sets the video's metadata.

This method will upload a video to a users account for that you need a user.  API keys are used for accessing public data not private data.

You will need to use Oauth2 authncate a user using one of the following scopes

[image]

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload']
DISCOVERY_URI = ('https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest')
CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH = 'client_secrets.json' # Path to client_secrets.json file.

# Set up a Flow object to be used if we need to authenticate.
flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(
  CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH, scope=SCOPES,
  message=tools.message_if_missing(CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH))
```

Comment: are there any ways to upload the video via a developer key or API key?   Since uploading video using OAuth is really annoying since you need to copy the link in the terminal and paste it to the browser and run through a lot of steps..

Comment: NO.  API keys are only going to give you access to public data and you cant upload something to someones account without their permission.  you need authorization for uploads  If you save the refresh token you should only have to do that once and then set your code up to use the refresh token to request a new access token as it needs